# HashMap android isn't getting called in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm using `HashMap` to put values in my database. I'm using it like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> queryValuess = new HashMap<>();
String premiu1 = String.valueOf(p1);
queryValuess.put("p1", premiu1.toString());
```

This works just fine EXCEPT when I put this inside of a function:

```
private void Premii10(int test) {
    HashMap<String, String> queryValuess = new HashMap<String, String>();

    p1=5;

    String premiu1=String.valueOf(p1);
    queryValuess.put("p1", premiu1.toString());
}
```

and I try to call it, for example, in a button click like this:

```
button click event {
    Premii10();
}
```

it's getting called, but the `queryValuess.put()` doesn't work. I know it's getting called because I've display a toast message and that's working. Do you have any idea why the `HashMap` doesn't work this way?

Comment: `Premii10` doesn't really do anything because `queryValuess` is a local variable. Did you mean to declare it outside the method?

Comment: how do you know that put dose not work ?

Comment: you must send a parameter when you call the method Premii10 (Param)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Not a local variable
Map<String, String> queryValuess = new HashMap<String, String>();

private void Premii10(Map<String, String> map) {
    p1 = 5;
    String premiu1 = String.valueOf(p1);
    map.put("p1", premiu1.toString());
}

// Use it like this
button click event {
    Premii10(queryValuess);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your click event

```
{
 Premii10();
}
```

but your method

```
private void Premii10(int test)
 {
  HashMap<String, String> queryValuess = new HashMap<String, String>();
  p1=5;
  String premiu1=String.valueOf(p1);
  queryValuess.put("p1", premiu1.toString());
  }
```

it expects a parameter of type int

Change your method call to

```
Premii10(1);
```

It should work now.